# How to get uniform color on selected text in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: colors, visual-studio-2012, customization

I change the Selected Text color which only allows you to change the background color but when I select some text, I notice the color is definitely not uniform all across. The selected text's background color looks different for a keyword vs an identifier.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Visual Studio 2012 doesn't like non-default fonts. Probably a bug in VS2012. Press the use Default fonts to solve the problem, so far that's the only solution I know.